# How to simplify the following expression by collecting logs?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, syntax

Consider the following function:

```
function[mN_,x_,b_]=-((1/(48*Pi^2*mN^3))*(8*b*mN^6*x^4 - 20*b*mN^6*x^2 + 
     6*mN^6*x^6*Log[b*mN + mN] - 
         3*mN^6*x^4*Log[b*mN + mN] + 21*mN^6*x^2*Log[b*mN + mN] - 
         6*mN^6*x^6*Log[mN^3*x^2*(b*mN - 3*mN) + mN^3*(mN - b*mN)] + 
         3*mN^6*x^4*Log[mN^3*x^2*(b*mN - 3*mN) + mN^3*(mN - b*mN)] + 
         3*mN^6*x^2*Log[mN^3*x^2*(b*mN - 3*mN) + mN^3*(mN - b*mN)] + 
         6*mN^6*x^6*Log[mN^3*(b*mN + mN) - mN^3*x^2*(b*mN + 3*mN)] - 
         3*mN^6*x^4*Log[mN^3*(b*mN + mN) - mN^3*x^2*(b*mN + 3*mN)] - 
         3*mN^6*x^2*Log[mN^3*(b*mN + mN) - mN^3*x^2*(b*mN + 3*mN)] - 
         3*(2*mN^6*x^6 - mN^6*x^4 + 7*mN^6*x^2)*Log[mN - b*mN] + 
         8*(2*mN^6*x^6 - 3*mN^6*x^4 + 3*mN^6*x^2 + mN^6)*
      Log[(2*mN*x)/(b*mN + mN)] + 
         12*b*mN^6));
```

It contains terms like g*Log[f1], g*Log[f2], where f1,f2 are some functions; so it may be simplified to g*Log[f1*f2]. However, commands like Simplify do not work:

```
Assuming[0<b<1&& mN > 0&& 0<x<1/2,Simplify[function[mN,x,b]]]
```

> -(1/(48 [Pi]^2))mN^3 (6 x^6 log(mN^4 (-(b+3) x^2+b+1))-6 x^6 log(mN^4 (b (x^2-1)-3 x^2+1))-3 x^4 log(mN^4 (-(b+3) x^2+b+1))+3 x^4 log(mN^4
> (b (x^2-1)-3 x^2+1))-3 x^2 log(mN^4 (-(b+3) x^2+b+1))+3 x^2 log(mN^4
> (b (x^2-1)-3 x^2+1))+3 (2 x^4-x^2+7) x^2 log((b+1) mN)-3 (2 x^4-x^2+7)
> x^2 log(mN-b mN)+8 b x^4-20 b x^2+16 x^6 log((2 x)/(b+1))-24 x^4
> log((2 x)/(b+1))+24 x^2 log((2 x)/(b+1))+8 log((2 x)/(b+1))+12 b)

Could you please tell me the rule allowing to reduce the expression?

Update: Thanks to @DanielHuber and @UlrichNeumann. The solution is to combine FullSimplify with the assumptions on parameters b,mN,x:

Assuming[0<b<1&& mN > 0&& 0<x<1/2,FullSimplify[function[mN,x,b]]]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELXFu.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELXFu.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying `FullSimplify` in the function definition results in:

[image]

If you the add a replacemet rule the number of Logs is reduced to 5:

```
function[mN_, x_, b_] = ... // FullSimplify) /. Log[x1_] - Log[x2_] -> Log[x1/x2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it still does not work properly, as it still does not collect the logs. I tried to add Assumptions (in my case, $0<b<1$, $mN>0$, $0<x<1/2$) but it still does not work.

Comment: See my update above.

Answer (score 2):

Try `FullSimplify` (as proposed by @DanielHuber) and afterwards the rule `Log[a_ b_] -> Log[a] + Log[b]`

```
FullSimplify[-((1/(48*Pi^2*mN^3))*(8*b*mN^6*x^4 - 20*b*mN^6*x^2 + 
       6*mN^6*x^6*Log[b*mN + mN] - 3*mN^6*x^4*Log[b*mN + mN] + 
       21*mN^6*x^2*Log[b*mN + mN] - 
       6*mN^6*x^6*Log[mN^3*x^2*(b*mN - 3*mN) + mN^3*(mN - b*mN)] + 
       3*mN^6*x^4*Log[mN^3*x^2*(b*mN - 3*mN) + mN^3*(mN - b*mN)] + 
       3*mN^6*x^2*Log[mN^3*x^2*(b*mN - 3*mN) + mN^3*(mN - b*mN)] + 
       6*mN^6*x^6*Log[mN^3*(b*mN + mN) - mN^3*x^2*(b*mN + 3*mN)] - 
       3*mN^6*x^4*Log[mN^3*(b*mN + mN) - mN^3*x^2*(b*mN + 3*mN)] - 
       3*mN^6*x^2*Log[mN^3*(b*mN + mN) - mN^3*x^2*(b*mN + 3*mN)] - 
       3*(2*mN^6*x^6 - mN^6*x^4 + 7*mN^6*x^2)*Log[mN - b*mN] + 
       8*(2*mN^6*x^6 - 3*mN^6*x^4 + 3*mN^6*x^2 + mN^6)*
        Log[(2*mN*x)/(b*mN + mN)] + 12*b*mN^6))] /. 
 Log[a_ b_] -> Log[a] + Log[b]

(*(1/(48 \[Pi]^2))mN^3 (-4 b (3 - 5 x^2 + 2 x^4) +3 x^2 (-7 + x^2 - 2 x^4) (Log[1 + b] + Log[mN]) - 
8 (Log[2] + Log[x/(1 + b)]) +x^2 (3 (7 - x^2 + 2 x^4) Log[mN - b mN] - 
8 (3 - 3 x^2 + 2 x^4) (Log[2] + Log[x/(1 + b)]) + 3 (-1 - x^2 + 2 x^4) (Log[1 - b + (-3 + b) x^2] - Log[1 + b - (3 + b) x^2])))*)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still does not collect the logs. However, if specifying particular assumptions about b,x,mN (please see the update to my question) and adding FullSimplify, the logarithms get collected properly. That's my fault that I did not specify the assumptions.